# Why doesn't this constructor allow this function to print hello world?

Tags: python, class, object, printing, constructor

I'm trying to learn about python classes and objects but I'm having difficulty learning how the objects and classes work in python compared to other programming languages like Java. For example in this simple Java code, I managed to print `hello world` from creating an object of the Class `Hello` and calling a method named `greeting`

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    Hello test = new Hello();
    test.greeting();
    
   }
}
class Hello{
    String hello = "hello world";

    public void greeting(){
        System.out.println(hello);
  }
}
```

However, when I try to do the same in python it doesn't seem to print anything

```
class test:
    hello = "hello world"

    def greeting():
        print(hello)

t = test()
t.greeting
```

I even tried to use a constructor but still, nothing is printed out

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = "hello world"

    def greeting(self):
        print(self.hello)

t = test()
t.greeting
```

All I'm trying to do is to make a class which contains a variable within it and then print that variable with a function in that exact class, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In neither example do you *call* the method, `t.greeting()`. In the first you need to access the class attribute via the class (`test.hello`) or the instance (`self.hello`). I'd recommend reading e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot but when do I know when to call a method by itself without the brackets and when to call a method with the brackets?

Comment: You *can't* call a method without the brackets. Without the brackets you're just accessing the attribute, not calling the value.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hello` is a class attribute. They can be accessed with `classname.classattribute`, so in this case: `Test.hello`.

```
class Test:
    hello = "Hello world"

    def greeting(self):
         print(Test.hello)
```

In python functions are objects too: `t.greeting` **is** the method; `t.greeting()` calls the method.

```
t = Test()
t.greeting()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call greeting, like  this `t.greeting()`.

For your first pyhton try, when you access class variable you might need to do it like this `print(test.hello)`